# Speech Recognition Plugin in Cordova listens only once

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, speech-recognition, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin for Speech Recognition in Cordova/Ionic.
https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin

The recognition only works once for me when I open the app for the first time (Android)

I don't see any error in the debugger. The recognition.start() fires a second time and i hear the sounds (Start & stop). 
However the onresult event only fires the first time.

```
   $scope.record = function(){     
   recognition = new SpeechRecognition(options);
        recognition.onresult = function(event) {
            console.log("On Result called");
            if (event.results.length > 0) {
                console.log(event.results[0][0].transcript);
            }else{
                console.log("no word");
            }
        };
        recognition.start();
   }
```

Any suggestion on this.

Comment: there is an open issue. https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin/issues/50 Will try to look into it when I have some time.

Comment: I fixed it last week, let me know if you still have issues

Answer (score -1):

Use ng-speech-recognition directive, you don't need to install any Cordova plugin to your hybrid app:

[ng-speech-recognition](https://github.com/Devniz/ng-speech-recognition)